# Error when execute code for Boto3 with AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sdk, boto3

I'm working on a python code to use the Boto3SDK to speak with AWS but i have some error, i'm a newbie in python.

This is the code :

```
import logging
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class AutoScalingWrapper:
    def __init__(self, autoscaling_client):
        self.autoscaling_client = autoscaling_client

    def describe_group(self, group_name):
        try:
            response = self.autoscaling_client.describe_auto_scaling_groups(
                AutoScalingGroupNames=[group_name])
        except ClientError as err:
            logger.error(
                "Couldn't describe group %s. Here's why: %s: %s", group_name,
                err.response['Error']['Code'], err.response['Error']['Message'])
            raise
        else:
            groups = response.get('AutoScalingGroups', [])
            return groups[0] if len(groups) > 0 else None
```

This is how i try to use it :

```
from main import AutoScalingWrapper

u = AutoScalingWrapper("ASGName")
print(u.describe_group())
```

But it result an error :

```
line 4, in <module>
    print(u.describe_group())
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: AutoScalingWrapper.describe_group() missing 1 required positional argument: 'group_name'
```

Anyone can help me please ?

execute python code to use the Boto3SDK with AWS

Comment: Look at `def describe_group(self, group_name):` - that method sets a group name, it doesn't return anything printable. You need to supply a group name when calling.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problems.

First `AutoScalingWrapper` is expecting a client as an argument, and you are passing a string. I strongly suggest type hints to prevent this.

Second, you are missing the group name in `describe_group`, so you need something like

```
from main import AutoScalingWrapper

import boto3

client = boto3.client('autoscaling')

u = AutoScalingWrapper(client)
print(u.describe_group("my-auto-scaling-group"))
```

Check the docs for more details: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/autoscaling/client/describe_auto_scaling_groups.html